# Nodejs oracledb different result with query executer and direct query from DBMS

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb, oracle-autonomous-db

When I execute my oracle query from the DBMS it returns correct data. But when i run the same query from from the nodejs oracledb code, results are wrong. I've searched this everywhere. but didn't get any solution. please help me. oracledb version is 5.3.0. I've also mentioned my query below.

```
SELECT
    ordersl3.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ordersl2.*,
            (
                SELECT
                    COUNT(*)
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            to_date(ordersl2.orderrelentrydate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + ROWNUM - 1 AS cal_date
                        FROM
                            all_objects
                        WHERE
                            ROWNUM <= to_date(ordersl2.orderconfirmdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_date(ordersl2.orderrelentrydate,
                            'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + 1
                    )
                WHERE
                    to_char(cal_date, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') IN ( 'SAT', 'SUN' )
            ) AS order_confirmation_week_end_count
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    ordersl1.obrowid,
                    MAX(ordersl1.ponumber)                      AS ponumber,
                    MAX(ordersl1.customerpartnum)               AS customerpartnum,
                    MAX(ordersl1.sourcepartnum)                 AS sourcepartnum,
                    MAX(ordersl1.poreceiveddate)                AS poreceiveddate,
                    MAX(ordersl1.poactioneddate)                AS poactioneddate,
                    MAX(ordersl1.reviseddeliverydate)           AS deliverydate,
                    MAX(ordersl1.orderqunatity)                 AS orderqunatity,
                    MAX(ordersl1.shadedescription)              AS shadedescription,
                    MAX(ordersl1.shiptodesc)                    AS shiptodesc,
                    MAX(ordersl1.globalcustomercode)            AS globalcustomercode,
                    MAX(ordersl1.globalsubbrandcode)            AS globalsubbrandcode,
                    MAX(ordersl1.orderstatus)                   AS orderstatus,
                    MAX(ordersl1.companynum)                    AS companynum,
                    MAX(ordersl1.companyid)                     AS companyid,
                    MAX(ordersl1.companyname)                   AS companyname,
                    MAX(ordersl1.ordernum)                      AS ordernum,
                    MAX(ordersl1.orderlinenum)                  AS orderlinenum,
                    MAX(ordersl1.orderrelnum)                   AS orderrelnum,
                    MAX(ordersl1.ordervalue)                    AS ordervalue,
                    MAX(ordersl1.sellingunitprice)              AS sellingunitprice,
                    MAX(ordersl1.expecteddeliverydate)          AS expecteddeliverydate,
                    MAX(ordersl1.acknowledgedeliverydate)       AS acknowledgedeliverydate,
                    MAX(ordersl1.orderrelentrydate)             AS orderrelentrydate,
                    MAX(ordersl1.orderconfirmdate)              AS orderconfirmdate,
                    MAX(mc.custname)                            AS custname,
                    MAX(ms.subbrandname)                        AS subbrandname,
                    MAX(ordersl1.order_confirmation_diff)       AS order_confirmation_diff,
                    MAX(ordersl1.order_confirmation_diff_hours) AS order_confirmation_diff_hours,
                    MAX(ordersl1.po_actioned_hours_diff)        AS po_actioned_hours_diff,
                    MAX(order_confirmation_holidays_count)      AS order_confirmation_holidays_count,
                    MAX(wsf.dispatcheddate)                     AS dispatcheddate,
                    MAX(wsf.invoicedate)                        AS invoicedate,
                    MAX(wsf.customeracknowdate)                 AS customeracknowdate
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            raworders.*,
                            ( raworders.order_confirmation_diff * 24 ) AS order_confirmation_diff_hours,
                            ( raworders.po_actioned_diff * 24 )        AS po_actioned_hours_diff
                        FROM
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    wof.*,
                                    (
                                        SELECT
                                            to_date(wof.orderconfirmdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_date(wof.orderrelentrydate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                                        FROM
                                            dual
                                    ) AS order_confirmation_diff,
                                    (
                                        SELECT
                                            COUNT(*)
                                        FROM
                                            blabs.t_holiday th
                                        WHERE
                                                th.globalplantcode = wof.globalplantcode
                                            AND th.active = 1
                                            AND th.holiday BETWEEN to_date(wof.orderrelentrydate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND to_date(
                                            wof.orderconfirmdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                                    ) AS order_confirmation_holidays_count,
                                    (
                                        SELECT
                                            to_date(wof.poactioneddate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_date(wof.poreceiveddate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                                        FROM
                                            dual
                                    ) AS po_actioned_diff
                                FROM
                                    sales.w_orderbook_f wof
                                WHERE
                                    wof.orderrelentrydate != TO_DATE('1901-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                            ) raworders
                    )                       ordersl1
                    LEFT JOIN masterdata.mst_customer mc ON ordersl1.globalcustomercode = mc.custid
                    LEFT JOIN masterdata.mst_subbrand ms ON ordersl1.globalsubbrandcode = ms.subbrandcode
                    LEFT JOIN sales.w_salesinvoice_f  wsf ON ordersl1.ordernum = wsf.ordernum
                                                            AND ordersl1.orderlinenum = wsf.orderline
                                                            AND ordersl1.orderrelnum = wsf.orderrelnum
                WHERE
                    ordersl1.poactioneddate BETWEEN TO_DATE('2022-03-04 18:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('2022-06-04 23:59:59',
                    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                    AND ordersl1.orderstatus = 0
                    AND mc.custid = 'B00019-T'
                    AND upper(concat(concat(TRIM(ordersl1.ponumber), ' '), concat(ordersl1.shiptodesc, concat(to_char(ordersl1.poreceiveddate),
                    concat(ordersl1.customerpartnum, concat(ordersl1.sourcepartnum, concat(ordersl1.subbrandname, concat(mc.custname,
                    ' ')))))))) LIKE '%%'
                    AND ordersl1.obrowid IS NOT NULL
                GROUP BY
                    ordersl1.obrowid
                ORDER BY
                    dispatcheddate
            ) ordersl2
    ) ordersl3
WHERE
    ( ordersl3.order_confirmation_diff >= 0
      OR ordersl3.order_confirmation_diff < 0 )
    AND ( ( ordersl3.orderconfirmdate IS NOT NULL
            AND ( ordersl3.order_confirmation_diff - ( ordersl3.order_confirmation_holidays_count + ordersl3.order_confirmation_week_end_count ) *
            24 ) <= 48 )
          OR ( ordersl3.orderconfirmdate IS NULL
               AND ( ( ( to_date(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - ordersl3.orderrelentrydate ) * 24 ) - ( ( ordersl3.order_confirmation_holidays_count +
               ordersl3.order_confirmation_week_end_count ) * 24 ) ) <= 48 ) )
    AND ( ( to_date(ordersl3.poactioneddate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_date(ordersl3.poreceiveddate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ) *
    24 <= 24 )
    AND ( ( ordersl3.dispatcheddate IS NOT NULL
            AND ordersl3.dispatcheddate <= ordersl3.deliverydate )
          OR ( ordersl3.dispatcheddate IS NULL
               AND to_date(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') <= ordersl3.deliverydate ) )
```

**[UPDATE]**
Filter 4400037844 PONUMBER in the nodejs oracledb output (4400037844 is there but its cannot be)
[image]

Filter 4400037844 PONUMBER in the direct query in the DBMS (4400037844 is not there. results are correct)

[image]

[COUNTS are also different using the same identical query].
oracledb nodejs
[image]

DBMS Direct Query
[image]

[UPDATE 2]
I cannot found any solution for this. So I had to make a separate java spring boot project to run this query. that resulted perfectly as same as the DBMS direct query.

So A lot of tests proved me that there is a bug in the node oracledb. But i cannot say whats that exactly. I think there is a query interpretation problem. So the conclusion is i cannot recommend nodejs oracledb to run complex queries since the results are unexpected until they fix it.

Comment: I have no idea what "correct" result is, as opposed to "wrong" simply by looking at more than 100 lines of code. What is wrong, though, is applying TO_DATE function to SYSDATE. SYSDATE is a function that returns DATE datatype, there's no point in "converting" it to DATE again. I'm not saying that this will fix your problems; just saying.

Comment: What does 'oracle query from the DBMS' mean?  You must have used some tool.  What tool?  My best guess is that in the tool that 'works', you have inserted data but not committed it.  So no other connection can see that data. The other guess is that the tool that 'works' is connecting to a different database or user than you are using with Node.js.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Im using ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER. When I run this query there its retrieving the correct records. But when i run the same query through  oracledb package in node js, records are wrong. this is not a database issue. seem a oracledb package issue. all the data is already available in the tables.

Comment: @ChristopherJones we're using a oracle cloud autonomous DB

Comment: @Littlefoot Thanks for the optimisation. but it didn't help with above mentioned matter

Comment: @ChristopherJones I've added the screen shot. hope u'll understand the real issue here

Comment: Did you commit the data in SQL Developer?  In both SQL Developer and Node.js the SQL query is executed and run in the database, so whatever is in the DB will be returned.  If you have a problem with node-oracledb, then share the SQL that creates the table and the data, and also a fully runnable JS test case that shows the problem.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example   Your screenshots don't help us analyze what your application is doing. I don't use SQL Developer so I don't know what the filter thing is actually doing or filtering on.  Keep debugging!

Comment: @ChristopherJones This is not the data committed by us. This database is belongs to a multinational company which is our client. What we're doing is only retrieving data for the presentation purpose. btw I've also tried this with the DBeaver. There also the results are correct. But node-oracledb results are wrong using the same query. This cannot be happen know. If the DB is returning the same how the results are not identical? Cant't it be a issue regarding query interpretation in node-oracledb?

Comment: I have reviewed the information supplied in this question.  It is insufficient to draw any conclusion about what the problem is, or where it may lay.  I'm not even sure what is wrong with the values - did you get extra rows, an unexpected column value or what?  We take data seriously and would definitely investigate if the requested test case was made available to us.

Comment: I've undeleted and edited some comments that contained or discussed rude language here, as well as rolled back the post edit that had the rude language edited in as a screenshot.  Please mind your language going forward.

Comment: I didn't post anything in purpose of insulting someone. I was telling the truth. This was a critical issue. How the same query is giving results in different places. But no one gave me a positive feedback except @Littlefoot. Truly I expected more than this from the oracledb contributor. Anyway Thanks guys.

Comment: I have given a lot of attention to this issue and would like to understand it.  However the requested information hasn't been supplied.  In particular there is no Node.js code shown, which makes it impossible to see what the intent was, or give an informed suggestion about investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is using `to_date(sysdate, ".....")`
In function `to_date` first paremeter is `varchar2`, but `sysdate` is date.
Oracle automatically convert `date` to `varchar2` using session nls parameters.
Result of conversation in node-oracledb and DBMS is different with different default session nls parameters in this apps.
And result of `to_date` is different.

I've had this mistake in my practice :)